# How to use Excel as a lookup in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

QQ - if I have an Excel spreadsheet on the classpath of a Mule app, can I do a lookup against it using dataweave alone?

Answer (score 4):

In order to use excel as a lookup you need to use the *[readUrl](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-readurl#readurl1)* function using the classpath protocol

```
var excel = readUrl("classpath://myExcelFile.xlsx", "application/xlsx")
---
(excel.mySheet filter ((entry, index) -> entry.foo == var.foo))[0]
```